# How to have ranking in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to implement ranking system in my MongoDB, and i am not able to have the slightest clue how to start it.

Here is my sample schema

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5aa639cb4add7a1c58507ac1"),
"vote" : -6,
"votedBy" : [ 
    "104093773763332"
],
"Fbid" : "109590486545309",
"imageId" : "86i1dr8apv",
"email" : "emnnevbjyo_1520686942@tfbnw.net",
"event" : "selfie",
"__v" : 0
```

}

I have multiple of those. Now i want to have a dynamic ranking. When the user is voted its vote increases, its rank in compared to other should increase, and when downvoted it should get lower.

Now only thing what I am thinking is using `$gt` in every document and comparing that from how many other elements it is greater. But won't it be too expensive?

Is there any better way to do it?

I have not made rank in the schema yet...!!!

Comment: Why don't you use sort for vote instead?

Comment: i would, and will, however, what i want to sort it according to the votes acquired and update the rank accordingly as the vote on a particular image will be changing

Comment: If someone vote, you only need to fetch your image list in your client side again. If you don't want this approach, you can send the image that user has just voted to your client and sort your image list by vote in your client side